# Bootstrap datepicker with highlate some range period

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

i use bootstrap datetimepicker: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

and its really easy to use:

```
$('#start').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
    useCurrent: true, //Important! See issue #1075
});
```

but into calendar I need to highlite some multiple range periods with green color etc.

from 1.June 2016 to 10.JUne 2016,
from 10.July 2016 to 30. July 2016
etc...

How I can do that ? Do I need some for loop or?

Comment: If I look at the docs I don't see any callback that let's you handle this. You must know that there are better alternatives available (The `bootstrap datepicker` tag you added to the question is one of these alternatives). But if you really want to use your current datepicker you need to alter the generated HTML after it's rendered.

Comment: what is better alternatives that allow that ? so I need multiple ranges...

Comment: Is the [`disabledDates` or `enabledDates`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#disableddates) an option for you? Otherwise I can write an example in the other datepicker if you like.